# Q: Permanently minimize desktop taskbar in Raspbian

Tags: raspbian-buster, taskbar

I have Raspbian Buster running on a RPi4. I minimize the taskbar but after a reboot the taskbar is still there and I have to re-minimize it. Beside this post about [autohide](http://Right-click%20on%20the%20taskbar%20and%20select%20%22Panel%20Settings%22.%20Click%20on%20the%20%22Advanced%22%20tab,%20and%20check%20%22Minimize%20panel%20when%20not%20in%20use%22.) I have checked numerous others but still have not found where to set this permanently. I do not want the taskbar to be disabled but just always minimized even after reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution by modifying with `sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel`. Changed the values of the two lines below:

```
autohide=1          # 0 = no autohide
heightwhenhidden=0  # value = number of pixels
```